# Possible to disable 'reply to all' when sending mass e-mail?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook

A newsletter e-mail went out company wide today, and since then I've gotten several reply-to-all responses. I immediately e-mail the offending user to warn them of the issues this can cause, but I'd rather know if it's possible to block reply-to-all for these newsletters.

Is it possible to disable reply-to-all on a per-message basis?

(Using Outlook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your original message went out with some kind of global group of in the `TO:` or `CC:` fields of the message.  The simple solution is to always use **BCC:** for any large distribution lists instead of a TO/CC.  Then simply put your own email address or some other single address in the TO field.

Of course to help people understand why they recieved the message you could also mention in the message body or subject that this message was sent to a specific group.

Comment: Niiiiiice. We can use this! Learnt something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer you're looking for, but one method I've used in the past is to create a rule that automatically deletes all reply-to-alls,(i.e. "RE: Newsletter 2014")

Tools **>** Rules and Alerts **>** New Rule **>** Move messages with specific words in the subject to a folder **>** Specific words: "RE: Newsletter July 2014" **>** Move to "Deleted Items" **OR** (permanently) delete it **>** Finish

Comment: The intent of the question is to mitigate email server load, not my personal inbox. I appreciate the alternative perspective, however.